# Prove that if the square of a number $m$ is a multiple of 3, then the number $m$ is also a multiple of 3.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I'd like to prove that if ${m}^{2}$ is a multiple of $3$, then ${m}$ is also a multiple of $3$. Similarly, I'd like to **disprove** that if ${n}^{2}$ is a multiple of $4$, then ${n}$ is also a multiple of $4$.

Per the comment from @thisismuchhealthier, the context is that I'm studying the proof of the elementary theorem from analysis that there is no rational number whose square is $2$ and the related statements that $\sqrt{3}$ and $\sqrt{6}$ are both irrational, but there is a rational number whose square is $4$.

Comment: Hint 1: 3 is prime, Hint 2: the second requires only a counterexample

Comment: Since 3 is prime, then it seems very obvious to me that $m^2$ is or is not a multiple of 3 just the same as $m$ is or is not. 4, on the other hand, is composite, so that if $n \equiv 2 \mod 4$, then $n^2 \equiv 0 \mod 4$ but that also holds when $n \equiv 0 \mod 4$ to begin with.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Hint** $\ 3\mid (m\!-\!1)m(m\!+\!1)=\color{#c00}{m^3\!-m},\ $  so $\ 3\mid\color{#0a0}{m^3}\,\Rightarrow\, 3\mid \color{#0a0}{m^3}\!-(\color{#c00}{m^3\!-m}) = m$

Comment: You keep surprising me with strange solutions.

Comment: @BillDubuque Where is *barto*'s answer?

Comment: @BillDubuque Your solution is awesome! How you got this *strange* idea?

Comment: @pushpen.paul My ghost-answer re-appeared.

Comment: It's not strange at all. More like a little trick. Nice solution anyway.

Comment: @barto It is not clear what do you mean by *My ghost-answer*

Comment: In fact you make it even "simpler" by assuming $3\nmid m$. Then $3\mid(m-1)(m+1)=m^2-1$ and since $3\mid m^2$, we would have $3\mid m^2 - (m^2-1)=1$, absurd.

Comment: @DeathkampDrone This is is also *very elementary* and great! This is the advantage of such sites, even a very basic problem can be seen in variant ways.

Comment: @DeathkampDrone Right, but my goal was to give an example of a "direct" proof, i.e. not by contradiction.

Comment: I'm not saying my proof is better than yours, in fact I prefer yours since as you said it does not resort to proof by contradiction. I was just showing how one can devise different tricks to solve elementary problems.

Comment: @DeathkampDrone Both proofs are trivially *equivalent* (even an automated theorem prover can rewrite one to the other). Generally it's better to avoid contradiction when it is not needed since doing so is often constructively fruitful (e.g. consider Euclid's proof of infinitely many primes).

Comment: The only reason I posted it is because it involves $m^2$ and not $m^3$, which at least in my opinion makes it nicer given the initial information we had (and kind of justifies the proof by contradiction). Anyway, I hope you don't mind me posting the same proof written in a slightly different manner.

Comment: @DeathkampDrone Your comments are quite welcome! The point of my reply was simply to explain why I chose the direct way vs. the more common proof by contradiction. Generally, I like to stimulate reasoning "outside of the box".

Comment: @BillDubuque This answer looks very elegant and I have no doubt that it is correct and finding a direct proof is impressive, unfortunately I am too ignorant to understand it and have thus accepted another answer. Perhaps some day in the **very** distant future I'll know enough to understand it.

Comment: @Ursus Please accept the answer you find most helpful. I can explain the above further if you tell me what is not clear to you. The first divisibility comes from the fact that one of $3$ consecutive integers must be divisible by $3$, hence so is their product. The final divisibility is true because multiples of $3$ are preserved under differences: $\,3a-3b = 3(a-b).\ \ $

Comment: @BillDubuque As a demonstration of my ignorance, I was unaware that the product of 3 consecutive integers is divisible by 3. However, I just read a couple of inductive proofs and it makes sense, so thanks for enlightening me. As I read your answer, I _think_ I see that it proves that if ${m}$ is divisible by 3, then ${m}^{3}$ is also divisible by 3. However, I guess it still escapes me how it directly proves that this also means that ${m}^{2}$ is divisible by 3 which I assume is the implication. I don't doubt the validity as I've tested it on several multiples of 3, just don't understand it.

Comment: @Ursus $ $ Great! $ $  Suppose that $\,3\mid m^2.\,$ Then $\,3\mid m^3 = m\cdot m^2.\,$ By my proof, $\,3\mid m^3\Rightarrow\,3\mid m,\,$ completing the proof. In your prior comment you seem to have read the implication in the wrong direction. Please feel welcome to ask further questions if need be.

Comment: @BillDubuque Thanks! You are both correct that I was reading the implication the wrong way. It now makes sense.

Answer (score 7):

If $m = 3k+1$, then 
$$
m^2 = 9k^2 + 6k + 1 = 3(3k^2 + 2k) + 1
$$ 
and if $m = 3k+2$, then
$$
m^2 = 9k^2 + 12k + 4 = 3(3k^2 + 4k+1) + 1
$$
Thus, if $m^2$ is a multiple of $3$, then $m$ is a also a multiple of $3$.

(because if $m$ is not a multiple of $3$, then neither is $m^2$)

Answer (score 2):

**First part:**

Consider three cases where $m$ is of the form $3k, 3k+1$ and $3k+2$ respectively. Squaring, you'll get only the first one (of the form $9k^2\equiv3k^2$) is the multiple of $3$ (the other two are $9k^2+6k+1=3(3k^2+2k)+1\equiv3k^2+1$ and $9k^2+12k+4=3(3k^2+4k)+1\equiv3k^2+4 \equiv3k^2+1$). Now convince yourself that for $m^2$ to be a multiple of $3$, $m$ must be of the form $3k$, i.e., $m$ is a multiple of $3$.

*I put $\equiv$ signs as when dividing by $3$ these expressions are equivalent.*

Other (elegant) way to state this problem is: Since $3$ is a prime and $3 | m^2=m\times m$, hence $3$ must be a factor at least one the factors of $m^2$; i.e. $3 | m$.

**Second part:**

As the wise people say: *One counter-example is sufficient to disprove*, take any $n$ which even **and** not a multiple of $4$ (like, $2$, $6$, $10$ etc). Clearly, $2^2=4$ is a multiple of $4$, but $2$ is not.

**I have created one follow-up question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/873439/divisibility-crieteria).**

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It is helpful. However, I believe if I follow your logic for multiples of 6--which is not a prime number--then I reach the same conclusion. That is if ${m}$ is a multiple of 6, then ${m}^{2}$ is also a multiple of 6. Thus, it seems that the defining characteristic of 3 is not that it is prime but something else. What am I missing?

Comment: @UrsusFrost If $m$ is a multiple of $6$, then $m^2$ will be as well. It is true. What makes you think that it is wrong?

Comment: @UrsusFrost Further, if $m$ is a multiple of $6$, $m^2$ is a multiple of $36$ as well.

Comment: @symplectomorphic I believe that **prime**, **composite** is not the correct characterization. It should be **perfect square** and **not perfect square**.

Comment: @UrsusFrost You are probably asking the reverse way: if $m^2$ is a multiple of $6$, then will $m$ be as well? Yes, as $6=3\times 2$ is not a perfect square.

Comment: _I have changed this characterization to **perfect square** and not a **perfect square** ._

Comment: It's not sufficient to just exclude perfect squares, the proper condition is that if $n$ is squarefree (that is, has no repeated prime factors) then $n \mid m \Leftrightarrow n \mid m^2$.

Answer (score 1):

First proof (I asume $m \in N$, is natural):

$m$ can be written as a product of different powers of prim numberts $p_i$
$m = p_1^{n_1}*p_2^{n_2}*...$

So $m^2 = p_1^{2n_1}*p_2^{2n_2}*... = 2^{2*n_1}*3^{2n_2}*...$.
Thus of $m^2$ is a multiple of $3$ it must be $n_2 >0$. Therefore $p_1^{n_1}*p_2^{n_2}*...$ is also a multiple of $3$.

Second disproof:
By counter example $n^2 = 4$ so it is a mutliple of 4. But $n = \pm \sqrt 4  = \pm 2$ is not a multiple of $4$

Answer (score 1):

We prove the contrapositive: If $3\nmid m$ then $3\nmid m^2$.
If $3\nmid m$, then $\gcd(3,m)=1$ because $3$ is prime. By Bézout's theorem, $mx+3y=1$ for integers $x,y$.
Squaring yields $m^2x^2+3(3y^2+2mxy)=1$, that is, $m^2X+3Y=1$ hence $\gcd(m^2,3)=1$.

Note: this solution does not rely on FTA or the uniqueness of quotient and remainder, but does extend to all primes.
*Correction (Thank you, Bill):* The common proof of Bézout's theorem *does* rely on uniqueness of quotient and remainder.

Comment: One easily extends the Bezout-based proof to show that  prime $\,p\mid ab\,\Rightarrow\,p\mid a\,$ or $\,p\mid b,\,$ and this immediately yields *uniqueness* of prime factorizations. So the above is essentially using a special case of uniqueness of prime factorizations. Further the proof of Bezout's identity for the gcd *does* (essentially) depend on the division algorithm (i.e. that $\,\Bbb Z\,$ is a Euclidean domain).

Comment: Oh yes sure, wasn't watchful when writing this, didn't have the proof in mind. I'll delete it because this makes it have no more value than other answers.

Comment: No need to delete, as its redundancy has importance still.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: To prove that if 3 divides $n^2$ then it divides $n$ you can prove that if 3 doesn't divide $n$, it doesn't divide $n^2$.

Comment: Do you mean $3\mid n^2\implies 3\mid n$? $3/n^2$ is usually used for division, not divisibility...

Comment: I used it as for divisibility. That's a symbole we use in the francophone mathematics.

Comment: But on an English-speaking site, using francophone notation is not likely to be helpful helpful to the questioner unless you define your notation. (I was not the downvoter, but I suspect your downvoter was confused by the notation.)

Comment: You're right I'll change it.
I'm not that idiot to use francophone symboles in an anglophone website. The reason I used it is that I didn't know that's a symbole you don't know ^^.

Comment: Well, personally, I know it, but it's very uncommon notation.

Comment: I appologize for that.

Comment: The French verb 'diviser' translates as 'to divide', e.g. '$3$ divides $n$'.

Comment: Oops thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

if $n$ is not a mutiple of three (it is $1$ or $2$ $\mod 3$), then $n^2$ is $1^2=1$ or $2^2=1$ $\mod3$ none congruent to three.
for the second question, look at $2$ and $2^2=4$