# Divisibility crieteria

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

This is a follow-up [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/872921/prove-that-if-the-square-of-a-number-m-is-a-multiple-of-3-then-the-number-m/872927).

The problem is:

> Given two natural numbers, $m$ and $n$, and $n \vert m^2$.
>
> Find necessary and sufficient conditions for $n \vert m$.

Here are what I find:

- Necessity

  > 1. $m \geq n$ (trivial)
  > 2. ?
- Sufficiency

  > 1. $n$ is prime - follows directly from **Matthias**'s answer
  > 2. $\color{#c00}{n \text{ is} ~square\!-\!free,}$ $\color{#c00}{\text{i.e., has no} ~repeated~prime~factor}$ (stated in **JHance**'s comment to my answer) - as pointed out by **gammatester**, it is wrong.
  > 3. ?

Help me to complete this list, folks.

Answer (score 1):

Your statement is **wrong**. For every $n$ set $m=n$ and you have $n|m^2$ and $n|m.\;$ But $n$ is not necessarily square-free! Ex. $4|16$ and $4|4$ but $4$ is not square-free.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the solution. Do correct me if I am wrong.

> $n|m$ if and only if there is no such prime $p$ such that $p^2|n$.

`If` part then it is easy, for example $4|14^2$ but $4\nmid 14$.

For the `only if` part, we can show a contradiction.